# Flask Mail - Style some phrases

Tags: email, flask

I'm sending e-mails using Flask Mail, but for now, after reading the documentation, I didn't see how I cant format my text.

So my question is:
- Am I able to format the text? Such as using italic, bold, or even using a different font.

If possible, where how can I modify to add this functionality?

```
from flask import Flask
    from flask_mail import Mail, Message
    import os

    app = Flask(__name__)

    mail_settings = {
        "MAIL_SERVER": 'smtp.gmail.com',
        "MAIL_PORT": 465,
        "MAIL_USE_TLS": False,
        "MAIL_USE_SSL": True,
        "MAIL_USERNAME": os.environ['EMAIL_USER'],
        "MAIL_PASSWORD": os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
    }

    app.config.update(mail_settings)
    mail = Mail(app)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with app.app_context():
            msg = Message(subject="Test subject",
                          sender=app.config.get("MAIL_USERNAME"),
                          recipients=["<testacc@gmail.com>"], 
                          body="test email\nBest regards\n\nJohn Doe")

            mail.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include HTML in you message like so

```
msg.html = "<b>testing</b>"
```

or render prepared template

```
msg = Message(subject="Test subject",
              sender=app.config.get("MAIL_USERNAME"),
              recipients=["<testacc@gmail.com>"])

msg.html = render_template('emails/your_template.html')
mail.send(msg)
```

take a look [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/)